# Name in addColumns

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a problem when I put the property "addColumns" in a piece because it does not show the name of the property. This property is defined as "joinByOne". An example of what happens to me:

[image]

I tried to put the name of the title with the "partial" property but I didn't get it.

```
addColumns: [

    {
    name: '_type',
    label: 'Type',

    //partial: articleType => articleType.map(articleType => articleType.title).join(' ')

    /*partial: function(title) {
        if (!value) {
        // Don't crash if updatedAt is missing
        return '';
        }
        return self.partial('specialist', { title: title });
    }*/


    },
]
```

Is there an effective way to put the title in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial receives the value of the join, which you can call `_type`. Since it is a `joinByOne` that value will be the entire joined object, not just its title.

So you just need to write:

```
partial: function(_type) {
  if (!_type) {
    return 'None';
  } else {
    return _type.title;
  }
}
```

Note that it is ALWAYS possible for `_type` to be null, even if you make it `required`, because someone might move the type itself to the trash, etc.